# Help with WPF data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm new to WPF and I'm trying to figure out how data binding works, but I'm not having much luck.

I'm trying to start with something simple - binding the contents of a text box to a string variable in my program.

I read lots and lots of pages of MSDN documentation about data binding, XML namespaces, markup extensions, resources, dependency properties and whatnot, and I'm still not able to get it to work.

Here's my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <c:Foo x:Key="MyFoo"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="28"
                 Text="{Binding Source=MyFoo,
                                Path=BarProperty,
                                Mode=TwoWay,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And my MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfTest
{
    public class Foo : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BarProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Bar", typeof(String), typeof(Foo));

        public String Bar
        {
            get { return (String)GetValue(BarProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BarProperty, value); }
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyFoo = new Foo { Bar = "hello" };
        }

        public Foo MyFoo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would expect the text box to show "hello" when the program starts up, but it is empty.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you had read the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) you probably would have been able to figure everything out yourself.....

Comment: @H.B. I did read the Data Binding Overview, as well as numerous other MSDN documentation pages. In fact I was basing my code on the example under "Creating a Binding", but it did not work! All of their example used this `Grid.Resources` or `DockPanel.Resources` etc. section, which just screws things up for me.

Comment: Well, it is admittedly a common mistake to just type the key of a resource without the `StaticResourceExtension` or a class name which in both cases makes the `Source` a string. You can create your source right in XAML by the way, but you cannot use the binding markup extension for that but an actual Binding object where you then can specify the source in XML-element syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the source. Either:

Give the window a name  like Name="mywin", alter your binding witn ElementName="myWin"

Or set the window DataContext like:

DataContext="{Binding ElementName="myWin"} - you can also use a RelativeSource if you don't want the name I just couldn't post it untested - Bindings tend to require testing as you also noticed :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `DataContext` of your Window to itself.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    MyFoo = new Foo { Bar = "hello" };
}
```

This tells WPF to look for bindings within your class.

Every control can set a `DataContext` which says "when I bind, I want to bind to a property on this specific instance...  This is inherited, so if you set the `DataContext` of the `MainWindow` to itself, all controls inside of `MainWindow` will bind to properties on the `MainWindow`.

Comment: Doesn't help... text box is still empty

Comment: UPDATE: It works if I do that **and** remove the binding's `Source` property, and change its `Path` to `MyFoo.Bar`.

Comment: @HighCommander4: Was just going to note that you need to remove the source (other sources which can be used are `RelativeSource` and `ElementName`, if any is specified it will be used instead of the DataContext).

Comment: @HighCommander4: Yes, the source was overriding the DataContext.  Sorry about missing that in there..

Comment: Can you explain what the `Grid.Resources` section does? I'm finding I don't need it, but it's there in all the MSDN examples.

Comment: @HighCommander4: You're making a new instance of "Foo" that's available by a specific key.  You shouldn't need it at all.

Comment: @HighCommander4: Have you seen the [Resources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx)?